# In every non-separable incomplete inner product space, is there a maximal orthonormal set which is not an orthonormal basis?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Let $X$ be an inner product space.

An orthonormal subset $B \subseteq X$ is called:

(i) a **maximal orthonormal set** if there is no other orthonormal subset of $X$ that contains $B$

(ii) an **orthonormaml basis** if $\text{span}(B)$ is dense in $X$

Consider the following statements about $X$.

(a) $X$ is complete

(b) every maximal orthonormal subset of $X$ is an orthonormal basis for $X$

Note 1. The converse of (b) (i.e., every orthonormal basis for $X$ is a maximal orthonormal subset of $X$) is always true and easy to prove.

Note 2. The proof that (a) implies (b) is in essentially every textbook that covers Hilbert spaces.

Note 3. If $X$ is separable, then (b) implies (a). See:

- [Every incomplete inner product space has a maximal but incomplete orthonormal system](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4322847/every-incomplete-inner-product-space-has-a-maximal-but-incomplete-orthonormal-sy)
- [Example of complete orthonormal set in an inner product space whose span is not dense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483455/example-of-complete-orthonormal-set-in-an-inner-product-space-whose-span-is-not?rq=1)
- [Non total orthonormal set in a non Hilbert inner product space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3037033/non-total-orthonormal-set-in-a-non-hilbert-inner-product-space?rq=1)

**Question.** If X is not separable, does (b) imply (a)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, (b) implies (a) also in the case of non-separable inner product spaces. Assuming $X$ is not complete we construct below a maximal orthonormal set, the span of which is not dense in $X$. You need the Axiom of Choice to get the maximal set but with a little twist added in order to show maximality. Two useful lemmas:

Lemma 1: If $(u_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$ then $\ell(x)=\lim_n \langle u_n, x\rangle$ defines a continuous linear functional of $x\in X$. If $\ker\ell = X$ then $u_n \to 0$ (i.e. a Cauchy sequence that goes weakly to zero, converges to zero). Proof-hint: $(\|u_n\|)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in ${\Bbb R}_+$.

Lemme 2: Let $(u_n)_n$ be a Cauchy sequence with $\|u_n\|=1$ but which does not converge in $X$ and let $\ell$ be the associated linear functional. Then $M=\ker\ell$ is a proper closed subspace of $X$ and $M^\perp = \{0\}$.
Proof-hint: If $M^\perp$ contains a non-trivial element $z$ use Lemma 1 to show that $u_n\to c z$ for some constant $c$, contradicting the hypotheses.

Now, consider the collection $\Lambda$ of orthonormal subsets of $M$ with a partial order given by inclusion. Then $\Lambda$ is inductively ordered
and by Zorn, $\Lambda$ has a maximal element which we denote ${\cal B}$.
Let $N\subset M$ be the closure of the span of ${\cal B}$.
Several cases must be considered.

1. If $N=M$ the proof is over by Lemma 2. ${\cal B}$ is maximal but does not generate $X$.
2. if $N^\perp=\{0\}$ the proof is also over (for the same reason).
3. If $N^\perp\cap M\neq \{0\}$ that would
   contradict maximality of ${\cal B}$ so we may assume that this intersection is trivial.
4. If $N^\perp$ contains at least two independent elements $p_1,p_2$ then
   $q=p_1/\ell(p_1)-p_2/\ell(p_2) \in N^\perp\cap M$, again contradicting maximality of ${\cal B}$.
5. There remains just one case to consider, i.e. that  $N^\perp$ is one-dimensional, whence generated by
   one unit vector $p\in X\setminus M$
   and that $M\setminus N$ contains some non-zero vector $q$.
   Let ${\cal B}'={\cal B} \cup \{p\}$ and let $H$ be the closed span
   of ${\cal B}'$. By orthonormality, it is the direct sum of $N$ and the span of $p$.
   First, we must have $H^\perp=\{0\}$ so ${\cal B}'$ is indeed a maximal orthonormal set in $X$.
   Second, suppose that $q\in H$. Then
   $q=cp + n$ with $c$ a constant and $n\in N$. But as $\ell(p)\neq 0$ and $0=\ell(q)=c \ell(p) + \ell(n) = c \ell(p)$ we wee that $c=0$ so $q\in N$ contrary to hypothesis. Thus, the orthonormal set ${\cal B}'$ must be maximal but not generating.

Comment: I am not sure I can follow your proof entirely. First question: What's the relation between V and M?

Comment: I realize that I wrote $V$ instead of $X$ for the incomplete inner product space. (I think simply because the first link does that - I should perhaps change that...). I never use a completion of $V$. I define the linear function $\ell$ from a non-converging Cauchy sequence and then define $M$ as the kernel of $\ell$ (in the incomplete space $V$).

Comment: I have two questions: 
(a) In Lemma 1, why is $\ell$ continuous? 
(b) In Lemma 2, why is $M^{\perp} = \{0\}$? (Your hint wasn't enough for me.)
I understand the rest of the proof perfectly

Comment: For Lemma 1, linearity should be clear? and $(u_n)$ is Cauchy whence bounded so the same is true for $\ell$ as a linear functional. For Lemma 2 suppose there is $z\in M^\perp$ of norm one and let $c=\ell(z)$. Then for any $x\in X$ the vector $x-z<z,x>$ is in $M$, i.e. in the kernel of $\ell$. Thus,  $0=\lim_n <u_n,x-z<z,x>>= \lim_n<u_n-cz,x>$. By lemma 1 we must have $u_n\to cz$, so $u_n$ did in fact converge in $X$.

Comment: Ah, I see about Lemma 2 now, you are using that $M^{\perp}$ cannot have dimension greater than 1. And I see now that the continuity in Lemma 1 is consequence of the continuity of the norm, Cauchy-Schwarz, and the boundedness of the Cauchy sequences (as you said). Thank you. Great answer.